# Function from require() throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

As a beginner to NodeJS this might be straigtforward but yet I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong

My home.js file is as follow

```
module.exports = function (deps) {
  var sample = require('../lib/sample'), // My own library
      express   = require('express'),
      router    = express.Router();

  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
     op = sample.parse('hi'); // Error here
     res.send(op);
  });

  return router;
 };
```

Under lib folder, my sample.js code is

```
module.exports = function () {

  function parse(text) {
      return 'hello' + text;
  }

  return {
      'sample': {
          'parse': parse
      }
  };
};
```

But I get an error saying `undefined is not a function` on the highlighted line. Can anyone let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you export a function, `sample` will be a function now. You need to explicitly execute it to get the same object. So, you need to do something like this

```
var sample = require('../lib/sample')().sample
```

Now, the `require` statement returns the function, and we immediately execute it, which returns an object with `sample` property. Since you are interested in `sample` property only, we get only the `sample` property.

If you were planning to hide the implementation of `parse` from the users, I would suggest doing

```
function parse(text) {
    return 'hello' + text;
}

module.exports = {
  'parse': parse
};
```

Now, you are simply exporting the `parse` function, in an object and the code which requires this module will be able to use `parse` function, like you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `module.exports` evaluates to a function which when called yields the object containing the `parse` function you are trying to call, under some nesting. You might try restructuring your sample.js file to look like this:

```
function parse(text) {
    return 'hello' + text;
}

module.exports = {
    parse: parse
};
```

Unless you really need the function wrapping shown in your example. In that case you'll have to unwrap it where you import it, so something like this:

```
var sample = require('../lib/sample')().sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `exports` to:

```
module.exports = function () {

  function parse(text) {
      return 'hello' + text;
  }

  return {
      'parse': parse
  };
};
```